# Parse JSON file that has nested keys

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have a JSON file that contains nested key-value pairs. My JSON file looks like this

```
{
   "TagName1":{
      "TestCaseName1":{
         "Status":"pass",
         "RunTime":"063045"
      },
      "TestCaseName2":{
         "Status":"fail",
         "RunTime":"064045"
      }
   },
   "TagName2":{
      "TestCaseName3":{
         "Status":"pass",
         "RunTime":"073045"
      },
      "TestCaseName4":{
         "Status":"fail",
         "RunTime":"074045"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to fetch the name of test cases based on their `Status`. Is there a way to do fetch nested key-values from JSON file?

I tried to solve this problem by using Reader and creating nested Hashmap of key-value pair, something like this

```
try{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reader reader = Files.newBufferReader(Paths.get(filePath));
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>> parsedJson = gson.fromJson(reader,HashMap.class);
}
```

I am struck at extracting the Status value. Is there a way to read the `Status` value and fetch the name of test case.

Comment: Do you need to do it with exactly gson library?

Comment: No @gdomo. Any solution would have worked for me. BTW thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

With the gson library it could be achived like this:

```
final List<String> failedCases = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString)
        .getAsJsonObject().entrySet()
        .stream() // get stream of all json entries, i.e. tags
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // get stream of tag values
        .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
        .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream()) // get stream of all test cases entries (name to value)
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getAsJsonObject() // filter test cases with "failed" Status value
                .get("Status").getAsString().equals("fail")
        )
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // get test cases names
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

@gdomo 's answer is pretty clean, here is how you can do the same with jackson

```
Map<String, Map<String, TestCase>> json = objectMapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<>() {});
    List<String> passes = json
            .values() // Lists of Entry { testCaseName: TestCase } grouped by tagName
            .stream().flatMap(entry -> entry.entrySet().stream())   // 1 list of all Entries { testCaseName : TestCase }
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getStatus().equals("pass")) // filter entries that pass
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)       // get the testCaseNames of entries that pass
            .toList();
```

notice I am using a defined TestCase class "which is cleaner practice"

```
public class TestCase {
    @JsonProperty(value = "Status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty(value = "RunTime")
    private String runtime;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try library *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(jsonString);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("**.*[value.Status='pass']*.get(..key)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
[ "TestCaseName1", "TestCaseName3" ]
```